# Validating multipart-form data parsed through multiparty and validation through express-validator

Tags: node.js, validation, express, multipartform-data

I am sending multipart form data and saving it on server but data is being saved without any validation. To parse the data I have used [multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty/) and [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) for post data valdation but i am saving data without any validation.

To send this data to the server I am using postman.

my code on sever side is as follows

```
exports.signup = function(req, res) {
  var form = new multiparty.Form();

  // Validation checks
  req.assert('first_name', 'first name is required').notEmpty(),
  req.assert('last_name', 'last name is required').notEmpty();
  req.assert('email', 'valid email is required').notEmpty().isEmail();
  req.assert('password', 'password field is required').notEmpty().len(6, 10);

  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if( !errors){
      form.parse(req, function(err, body , files) {
          ////////
          code to save the data on server goes here
      });

  }
  else if (errors) {
      return res.status(400).send({
          'error': errors
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're trying to validate body fields before they are parsed, which isn't possible.

You have to move your `req.assert()` and `req.validationErrors()` lines inside your `form.parse()` callback. For example:

```
exports.signup = function(req, res) {
  var form = new multiparty.Form();
  form.parse(req, function(err, body, files) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).end();

    req.body = body;

    // Validation checks
    req.assert('first_name', 'first name is required').notEmpty(),
    req.assert('last_name', 'last name is required').notEmpty();
    req.assert('email', 'valid email is required').notEmpty().isEmail();
    req.assert('password', 'password field is required').notEmpty().len(6, 10);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
      res.status(400).send({
        'error': errors
      });
    } else
      res.status(200).end();
  });
};
```