# Express validator with Multiparty does not work Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

currently im working on expressjs and using `express validator` for validation and `Multiparty` for handling multipart form.

the case is when i wanna assert my text forms the `express-validator` does not work the way it should because i use `multiparty` as well.

here is my code.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const multiparty = require('multiparty');

app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));



app.post('/store', (req, res, next)=>{
  const form = new multiparty.Form();
  
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files)=>{
    req.assert('name','Store name is required.').notEmpty();
    req.assert('description', 'Store Description is required.').notEmpty();
    req.assert('category', 'Store Category is required.').notEmpty();
    
    const errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
      console.log(errors);
    }else{
      
     // upload the file and save the data;
    }
  });
  
});
```

> console.log(errors) result always returns an array contains 3 objects, it's always like that even i give value in name and description fields, it's still return as it.

[image]

i have read the similar issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517220/validating-multipart-form-data-parsed-through-multiparty-and-validation-through) but still cant solve my problem. help me.

> The Question is how to use Express validator and Multiparty together
>   to validate my fields??

Answer (score 0):

did you use `req.getValidationResult().` for see result of validation in this case ,that i see in docs:

```
req.getValidationResult().then(function(result){
})
```

Comment: i do, form.parse the first argument is req. 

form.parse(req, (err, fields, files)=>{
  so i can use req.validationErrors();
}